# In Inari, Konkon, Koi Iroha, what does the name on the blimp mean?

Tags: inari-konkon-koi-iroha

In episode two of Inari, Konkon, Koi Iroha, there was a scene where there was a blimp with a sign with a heart on it and some words "WE/MAX". What does WE/MAX mean?

[image: blimp]

Comment: Just as a note: The text on the side of the blimp reads シンワハウス, or "Shinwa House". This might be a real estate company in Japan, hence the pun on "RE/MAX" in the subs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Eric mentioned, "[シンワハウス (Shinwa House)](http://www.shinwahouse.co.jp/)" is a real estate company in [Iwate Prefecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwate_Prefecture) and the subtitles is referring to "RE/MAX", which is [famous for the iconic balloon](http://www.remax.com/c/corporate/the-balloon). The localization decided to use "WE/MAX" since they can't use the trademarked name "RE/MAX" and using "Shinwa House" pretty much has no meaning in English speaking countries. The combination of the balloon and "WE/MAX" was a localization compromise.

Comment: Actually, the name of the real-life company is 神話ハウス. Same reading, but different writing.

Comment: 伸和ハウス, actually.